# Add a new column in all mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a **practice** table like this:

```
    id     | otherColumn1 | otherColumn2 | otherColumn3
--------------------------------------------------------
    1      |  othervalue1 |  othervalue2 | othervalue3 
    2      |  othervalue1 |  othervalue2 | othervalue3
```

I have many other tables:

```
Person
Address
Contact
------
------
------
```

Now my task is to add **practiceId** column in every other table which will be a **foreign key from practice table**. Remember that some tables already have **practiceId** column so I don't need to change those tables.

Problem is that there are many tables. Can I do this with less queries Or can I write a efficient PHP script for this ?

I already have a php script that can get tables names from a particular database.

Thanks

Comment: If there are many tables - how to know WHICH table should be linked with practice table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really isn't a way to add a field to multiple tables at once. You will need to write a script for it. It shouldn't be a hard script to write, though:

A simple `SHOW TABLES` query will get you a list of tables which you can then loop through in PHP.

Within the loop, a `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename` query will give you the fields in the current table, which you can use to check if it already has the `practiceId` field, and then add it if necessary.

To add the field, use `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN practiceId INT` (I've assumed `INT`, but replace with however your field needs to be defined if you're using a different data type)

To add an index on the new column, you can also use `ALTER TABLE`, or use `CREATE INDEX`. To create a foreign key contraint use `ALTER TABLE` with `ADD FOREIGN KEY` argument (But I believe this only works with InnoDB tables).

Reference:

- [SHOW TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)
- [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)
- [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)
- [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html)
- [Foreign key contraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: OK. Thanks. Can you tell me a MySql query to add practiceId column in a single table? Then I will use this query in my php script loop.

Comment: @Awan - edited the answer to include `ALTER TABLE` (plus some reference links to the MySQL manual)

Comment: Thanks. This `Alter Table` query will simply add a new column. How can we add a new column as a foreign key ?

Comment: @Awan - `ALTER TABLE` also allows adding keys. See the manual page I linked for the full syntax. You can also use `CREATE INDEX` to do this too.